# How to use the filter generated using design function on Matlab?

Tags: matlab, filter

I have created a peaking filter with 800 Hz center frequency using the commands as follows:

```
fs = 44100;
N = 6; F0 = 800/(fs/2); BW = 50/(fs/2);
peakspec = fdesign.peak('N,F0,BW',N,F0,BW);
peakfilt = design(peakspec,'SystemObject', true);

% Input signal
x = 2*cos(2*pi*(80).*(0.01:0.0001:10))+3*cos(2*pi*(100).*(0.01:0.0001:10));
% Getting the filtered output
y = filter(peakfilt, x);
```

This last line gives the error: *Not enough input arguments.*

I do not understand why I get this error.

I looked it up on the website and came to know that peakfilt is a BiquadFilter and it would be helpful if someone could explain how to use a BiquadFilter.

Thanks.

Comment: Try fvtool(peakfilt)

Comment: You are creating a Biquad-Filter. Reading the documentation [link](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.biquadfilter-class.html), tells you to apply it in the following way: ` y =peakfilt(x);`

Answer (score 0):

You're very close and there isn't much else you need to change to get it working.

```
% Getting the filtered output
y = filter(peakfilt, x);
```

In this last line you are trying to the use the [filter function](https://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/data_analysis/filtering-data.html) to apply your custom biquad filter, **BUT** the *filter()* function takes 3 inputs (minimum) as described in the documentation:

```
y = filter(b,a,x)
```

Where b & a are your two arrays of filter coefficients and x is your input signal that you want to filter.

In your case, you are trying to pass the *peakfilt* system object as an input to the *filter()* and it is then throwing back the error *Not enough input arguments* because its expecting 3 inputs minimum and 2 of them to be filter coefficients.

Following the [biquad filter documentation](https://de.mathworks.com/help/dsp/ref/dsp.biquadfilter-class.html#bsfxujp-2) filtering an input requires a slightly different approach:

```
filteredOutput = biquad(input);
```

And in your case changing the last line to the following should solve it:

```
y = peakfilt(x);
```

To then see the frequency response of your filter have a look at *fvtool(filterObject);* (documentation with the biquad filter docs), in your case:

```
fvtool(peakfilt);
```

I hope this helps!